# Open list of files at function definition in Vim

Tags: windows, vim, cygwin, grep

Lets say I have a number of files within my source tree which contain a definition for the method `FindThisMethod()`. I would like to open all of these files in a single instance of gVim, in separate buffers, with the cursor at the line of the method definition.

On Windows XP using Cygwin I have tried things along the lines of:

```
gvim --remote-silent `grep -rnl --include=*.cs 'void FindThisMethod()' *`
```

This will load all the correct files in vim, but I'm still not sure how to get the cursor to the line matched by grep. Since vim supports the syntax `gvim +<line number> file.txt` I have tried combining awk with grep to produce a list of line numbers and file names:

```
grep -rn --include=*.cs "void FindThisMethod()' * | gawk -F: '{print "+"$2" "$1}'
```

Which produces:

```
+123 file.cs
+234 file2.cs
+345 file3.cs
```

But I'm unsure of how to use this with gvim to open the files at the given lines. I tried piping this output to `xargs -L 1 gvim --remote-silent` but this didn't work since launching the Windows binary of gvim from xargs failed.

There's got to be a better way : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build on the grep you've already used, you can do:

```
grep -rn --include=*.cs "void FindThisMethod()' > quick.txt

gvim -q quick.txt
```

This will load the results of the grep into vim's quicklist allowing you to do "copen" to view each search match in a mini window, "cn" to go to the next, "cp" to go to the previous.

```
Try: "help quickfix"
```

However, what might be better than grep would be to use vim with cscope.  Cscope integrates well with vim, builds a database which allows you to see, for example, every function called "myfunc" (:cs f s myfunc) or every function calling myfunc (:cs f c myfunc).  This also integrates with the quickfix window allowing you to navigate through the results.

```
Try: "help cscope"
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off using vim's builtin grep, which does that for you

```
gvim --remote...etc...etc '+grep --include=*.cs "void FindThisMethod()" *'
```

see

```
:help :grep
```

for more

Comment: I highly recommend the quickfix feature with the :grep or :vimgrep (I like the later although its probly slower; at least it always works).

Comment: Using vimgrep also works great, thanks, I wasn't familiar with it until now :)